# Using Docusign Connect with multiple environments

Tags: docusignapi

I am running into conflicts using Docusign connect with multiple environments.

My Sandbox account is being used by Staging, Review apps & Dev environments. Docusign Connect is sending out envelope-events to environments that have not created the envelope which is causing lots of confusion.

This must be a common issue - is there a recommended way of handling it?

---

The only work-around I can think of is to add an `sending_environment` custom field with each envelope and then filter out the envelope-events when they are sent to each environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we have gone for:

- Each Dev sets up their own 'user' account (invited via the docusign account dashboard)
- Devs use their credentials locally
- Staging & Review apps use the default sandbox docusign user account
- Production uses the default production docusign user account

Once this is done, we set up a permissions check on each envelope event that arrives, ensuring the user `<Email>` field matches that of the current environment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
      <EnvelopeStatus>
        <TimeGenerated>2020-05-18T12:00:00</TimeGenerated>
        <EnvelopeID>abcdef</EnvelopeID>
        <Email>me@gmail.com</Email>
      </EnvelopeStatus>
    </DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

This ensures Dev environments don't conflict with staging & review apps.

---

Next we need a way of distinguishing Staging and each Review app. For this we add a `<CustomField>` to each envelope that we create, and in Staging & Review app environments, add an additional check for that custom field to filter out any envelopes that were not created in the current environment.

---

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using custom fields is a good approach.
I assume when you say "multiple environments" you mean your company/app/IT etc. not DocuSign's.
If it was DocuSign's (demo/sandbox vs. production) you could tell based on many things, account number, envelope ID, URL etc.
in any event, putting a text field that you can retrieve on the other end is a good way to handle this.
What I think you can also do, is have a different DocuSign configuration for each of your environments, such that they use different URLs for the callback from DocuSign. That approach may be more or less work than the other approach. Your call.

Comment: "different DocuSign configuration for each of your environments, such that they use different URLs for the callback from DocuSign" -
I do have a different DocusignConnect configuration for each environment, but I have set them all to point at the same URL. Are you suggesting each environment/configuration should have a different URL to send to? I was wondering if it could be done in a cleaner way, for example by creating a different integration key or something like that.

Comment: My DocuSign Sandbox account is used by Staging, Local devs as well as dynamically created review apps. Yet all the DocuSign Connect logs are undistinguishable in the same area. Is there any way that within the same DocusignAccount we can have separate areas (accounts/users/groups?) so that each environment has it's own set of configuration and logs for example ?

Comment: I think your idea of using custom fields is a very good approach. You could use other meta-data, but custom text fields are exactly the way to use custom meta-data that fits your needs.

Comment: inbar-gazit , I also stepped in same issue: I have two different environment url for my webhook 1. Prod , 2.Preprod. I am using both the url in docusign's production account.  For preprod, I am using different user, but integrator key is same as prod user has, so do I need to create a new integrator for prepprod user as well for docusign connect ?

Comment: no, you can use the same in both